# Объединение двух запросов с COUNT

Tags: sql, oracle, запрос, объединение

Прошу прощения, если схожие вопросы уже были заданы, но сил разбираться самому уже не осталось. Oracle 12c SQL Developer.

Есть 2 запроса:

1. ```
   SELECT Наименование_продукции as Продукция, 
          COUNT(id_продукции) as Количество_выставок_продукции
   FROM ОРГАНИЗАЦИЯ_ВЫСТАВКИ
   GROUP BY Наименование_продукции;
   ```
2. ```
   SELECT Наименование_предприятия as Предприятия, 
          COUNT(id_стенда) as Количество_выставок
   FROM ОРГАНИЗАЦИЯ_ВЫСТАВКИ
   GROUP BY Наименование_предприятия;
   ```

По отдельности работают как надо. Но в задании сказано "Общий список продукции с количеством выставляемой и предприятий с количеством выставок - Запрос на объединение"

Пытался сделать вложенным запросом, пытался сделать через `JOIN` - ничего толкового не вышло, либо я просто недостаточно хорошо осознаю, как работает SQL Oracle. Через `Union` всё как бы объединилось, но просто в один столбец, что выглядит убого да и не скажешь даже, что требования задания выполнены.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это должно выглядеть. У одногруппников не спросить - с SQL никто, как и я, до этого не работал, все себе задания купили и "забили". Хотел сам сделать, разобраться, опираясь на их работы и интернет, но и вариант попался не самый удачный, слишком много `COUNT` везде. Уже около недели "стучусь головой" из-за нескольких запросов. Заранее огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Покажите, как должен выглядеть конечный результат. По тому, что написано в задании, я, например, не могу понять, что должно получиться. В крайнем случае, у преподавателя спросите. Пока не приходит ничего в голову, кроме `union` (а лучше `union all`), который вы уже пробовали (кстати, через `union` у вас должно было получиться два столбца, а не один).

Comment: К сожалению связаться с нашим преподавателем - задание не легче, чем то, что он нам задал) Как я понимаю, должны получиться 4 столбца: наименование продукции - количество продукции на выставке - наименование предприятия - количество выставок каждого предприятия.
 А юнион - да, он мне выдал 2 столбца (извиняюсь, описался в первый раз): Наименование продукции - количество продукции, и В НИХ ЖЕ снизу без каких-либо разграничений добавил в столбец с продукцией - предприятия, а в количество продукции - количество выставок. То бишь "каша малаша" вышла.

Comment: Ярослав, может вам надо попробовать пронумеровать строки 1-го и 2-го запросов, а затем их `FULL OUTER JOIN` по номеру строки?

Comment: Какой-то бред. У вас 5 предприятий и 10 продукций. Что с чем вы будете объединять?

Comment: @velial - возможно Вы правы, но как осуществить FULL OUTER JOIN именно по номерам строк - знания у меня нет, к сожалению)
AntonShchyrov - простите, не могу в одном комментарии 2 обращения сделать - Объединить, как видно в задании, надо запрос с "Продукцией и её выставляемым количеством" с запросом "Предприятий и количеством их выставок". То, что 5 предприятий и 7 видов продукции объясняется, по идее тем, что одно предприятие выставляет несколько видов продукции.

Comment: @Ярослав "Как я понимаю, должны получиться 4 столбца: наименование продукции - количество продукции на выставке - наименование предприятия - количество выставок каждого предприятия." - Это абсолютно бессмысленное действие с точки зрения SQL.

Comment: @Dmitry - вот честное Вам слово - при описании задачи кавычки поставил не зря, так как это реальная цитата из общего списка заданий) Про 4 столбца - тут уже чисто моё предположение, так как я просто иначе не представляю даже, как вообще может выглядеть то, что из этого объединённого запроса должно выйти)